# Why is mocha not stubbing this method in my Rails 3 integration test?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, minitest, ruby-mocha

I have the following:

```
  setup do
    Capybara.current_driver = Capybara.javascript_driver
    @project.user = @user
    @project.save
    Project.any_instance.stubs(:price_all)
  end
```

And yet I have a test failing because the Project.price_all method is being run:

```
/Users/me/code/rails/myapp/app/models/project.rb:178:in `price_all'
```

This was working properly until I upgraded to Capybara 2 and the latest version of capybara-webkit.

Why is that method still being run? And how can I fix?

Answer (score 0):

When you say "the `Project.price_all` method is being run", is that a typo, or is `price_all` really a class method? If it is indeed a class method, you'll want to use `Project.stubs(:price_all)` instead of including `any_instance` so the stub is directly on the `Project` class rather than an instance of `Project`. If that's not your issue, I'm not sure what else to suggest based on the code sample you've provided.

Comment: It's not a class method.  I just meant that the price_all method is being called on an instance of the Project class.